# Error parsing feedback. yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am facing the following error when i am trying to create a pod in kubernetes.
**error parsing feedback.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: mapping values are not allowed in this context**
Here is the code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-demo-1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: demo-container
    image: nginx
    env:
    - name: Username
      valueFrom:   
        secretKeyRef:   
          name: db-secret
          key: username
```

Comment: is it a K8S error? Or do you write your own code and it fails? If so, share it.

Comment: That `error converting YAML` error is highly likely to just be a syntactic problem in your file.  What you've included in the question looks valid; have you tried to use some other YAML tool (not Kubernetes specifically) to validate what you have locally?

Comment: @sakshi Jain : I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further .

Answer (score 0):

As per this [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-a-container-environment-variable-with-data-from-a-single-secret), I have reproduced your issue and without any error pod has been created.

- Initially, I have created the secret using the below command :

  `kubectl create secret generic db-secret --from-literal=username='backend-admin'`
- Then I used the same YAML file which was mentioned in the above question and created the pod accordingly.

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: secret-demo-1
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - name: demo-container
>     image: nginx
>     env:
>     - name: Username
>       valueFrom:   
>         secretKeyRef:   
>           name: db-secret
>           key: username
> ```

[image]

- You can also check the content of the SECRET container environment variable using below command :

  `kubectl exec -i -t secret-demo-1 -- /bin/sh -c 'echo $Username'`
- Can you try using the above steps and let me know if you face any error.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.